# Postgresql skipping some/many write queries when used along with python crawlers

Tags: django, postgresql, web-crawler

i am using postgres paired with django(python) and application is crawling internet for specific kind of data. As the crawlers find anything of their use they write it to the database. Now as the speed of crawlers is high and they are querying database by get_or_create(in django which checks for if the data is already in the database or not if it is not present then it makes a new row of it) All the cores on my machine are engaged to almost 99%. In that case when i trace the process,the postgres is skipping the write command for some or many instances.What can be the reason? Any recommendations in terms of change in architecture?

traced the crawler procedure manually and the process was printing the data it found but was not added to the postgres. That confirmed the data was getting lost.

Comment: It's hard to tell without any code. Are you sure that data doesn't exist in the database when it's being skipped? Do you see any exceptions raised during code execution?

Comment: I talked to someone on postgresql community on slack and they were pretty sure that the data was not getting lost but it was a lagg in inserting data which is why i was unable to see the updated data in the table. They recommended inserting data in batches and also tuning the batch size according to the resources on the machine.

Comment: No there were no exceptions raised the script worked smoothly but i didn't found data in the table even after 5 minutes of wait. Maybe that was due to my cores being 100% engaged in crawling.

Comment: Check the postgres logfile. (it could be deadlocks being aborted)

Comment: You can check lag theory by stopping your crawler. Stop it and watch your CPU of PC and database processes. Check pending queries `select * from pg_stat_activity`.

Comment: Also try running your crawler with CPU lower than 100% (e.g. reduce number of threads to 1) and examine the results.